# how to retrieve value in array from mysql table in java?

Tags: java, jdbc

i want to store string value in array or in  in separate variable   using java please short out my problem

Thanks

```
String a1,a2,a3;


 while (resultSet.next()) {
     isFound=true;
    jLabel2.setText("hello");



   String s1=resultSet.getString("Court_Num");
System.out.println(s1);

output s1=: 101

            102

            103

Desired out put: a1=101

                 a2=102

                 a3=103
```

Comment: what is a1 a2 and a3?do you want to append?

Comment: a1,a2,a3 are variable String type

Comment: actually, what is the exact output you get when you do `System.out.println(s1);`?

Comment: I'm confused - What is being asked here? What is "please short out my problem"?

Comment: problem is that i want to store s1 string in separate variable as given above code

Comment: i got following out put  s1=: 101

                              102

                              103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing I think for 1st record you want a1=101 for 2nd a2=102 etc

```
int i=1; 
while (resultSet.next()) {
if(i==1)
{String s1=resultSet.getString("Court_Num");
System.out.println(a1+"="+s1);}
if(i==2)
{String s1=resultSet.getString("Court_Num");
System.out.println(a2+"="+s1);}
if(i==3)
{String s1=resultSet.getString("Court_Num");
System.out.println(a3+"="+s1);}
i++
```

Comment: correct answer. exactly as required by OP in the question. LOL. by the way, you should vote to close as _Unclear Question_

Comment: @RafaEl I think OP is new to java so thinking to help

Answer (score 0):

The title mentioned using an array.  That would look something like this:

```
String[] a = new String[3];
for(int i=0; resultSet.next(); i++) {
    a[i] = resultSet.getString("Court_Num");
    System.out.println("a" + i + "=" + a[i]);
}
```